# What treatments help decrease the percentage of immature type III collagen fibers following a tendon injury?

Tags: treatment, tendinopathy, collagen

{1} mentions:

> A microscopic view of tendinosis reveals an increase of immature type III collagen fibers (mature type I fibers dominate in healthy tendon tissue).

What treatments help decrease the percentage of immature type III collagen fibers (and instead increase the type I collagen fibers) following a tendinopathy?

---

I unsuccessfully tried the following queries on Google, Google Scholar and PubMed:

- decrease the percentage of immature type III collagen fibers
- decrease type III collagen fibers

---

References:

- {1} Bass, Evelyn. "Tendinopathy: why the difference between tendinitis and tendinosis matters." International journal of therapeutic massage & bodywork 5, no. 1 (2012): 14. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3312643/